# XPATH 2.0 create query

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quo:Zaklad xmlns:quo="http://www.xxx.com/XMLSchema/Zaklad" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx.com/XMLSchema/xxx.xsd" quo:nr="356-12">
   <quo:id_produktu>304</quo:id_produktu>
   <quo:wersja_produktu>3</quo:wersja_produktu>
   <quo:Nazwa_produktu>
</quo:Zaklad>
```

How create query in xpath 2.o which return id_produktu?

Comment: As per Vaman's comment, do you need the name of the node without the namespace (id_produktu) or do you require the VALUE of the node (304)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get namespace agnostic xpath using local-name, like so:

```
/*[local-name()='Zaklad']/*[local-name()='id_produktu']/text()
```

Comment: I think this XPath will return you the text of the node `id_produktu` and the OP is interested in getting node name `id_produktu`

Comment: @VamanKulkarni - good point - OP's question is ambiguous. I've posted comment to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the simple case that you're using a namespace manager set up with the same namespaces, could you use the following?

```
/quo:Zaklad/quo:id_produktu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `local-name()` function to get the name of the node.

```
local-name(/*/quo:id_produktu)
```

Above xpath expression will return you `id_produktu`.  You should let Xpath engine know about the namespace prefixes that is present in xpath by using the programming language of your choice.

You can get more information on this function **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#node)**